# why excel is needing to repair thee xlsx file after i modify it with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

why excel is needing to repair the xlsx file after I modify it with openpyxl?
here is my code.

```
    try:
        import PySimpleGUI as sg
        from openpyxl import Workbook
        from openpyxl import load_workbook
    except:
        print('Import failed')
    
    sg.theme('DefaultNoMoreNagging')
    
    wba="payroll.xlsx"
    
    wb = load_workbook(wba)
    
    ws = wb.active
    
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Please fill out the following fields:')],
        [sg.Text('Name', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Hours Worked on Monday', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Hours Worked on Tuesday', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Hours Worked on Wednesday', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Hours Worked on Thursday', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Hours Worked on Friday', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Hours Worked on Saturday', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Hours Worked on Sunday', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText()],
        
        
        [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]
    ]
    
    list1 = ['D','F','H','J','L','N','P']
    
    window = sg.Window('Hours Worked entry form', layout)
    
    def john():
        for n in range(0,7):
            ws[str(list1[n])+'3'] = int(values[n+1])
    
    def alice():
        for n in range(0,7):
            ws[str(list1[n])+'4'] = int(values[n+1])
    
    def louis():
        for n in range(0,7):
            ws[str(list1[n])+'5'] = int(values[n+1])
    
    def samantha():
        for n in range(0,7):
            ws[str(list1[n])+'6'] = int(values[n+1])
    
    def ron():
        for n in range(0,7):
            ws[str(list1[n])+'7'] = int(values[n+1])
    
    def jessica():
        for n in range(0,7):
            ws[str(list1[n])+'8'] = int(values[n+1])
    def rachel():
        for n in range(0,7):
            ws[str(list1[n])+'9'] = int(values[n+1])
    
    
    def clear_input():
        for key in values:
            window[key]('')
        return None
    
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == 'Submit':
            sg.popup('Data saved!')
            if values[0] == 'John':
                john()
                clear_input() 
            elif values[0] == 'Alice':
                alice()
                clear_input() 
            elif values[0] == 'Louis':
                louis()
                clear_input() 
            elif values[0] == 'Samantha':
                samantha()
                clear_input() 
            elif values[0] == 'Ron':
                ron()
                clear_input() 
            elif values[0] == 'Jessica':
                jessica()
                clear_input() 
            elif values[0] == 'Rachel':
                rachel()
                clear_input() 
            else:
                sg.displau
                
    
    try:
        wb.save(wba)
        window.close()
    except:
        print('The file being saved is open')
    window.close()

It is saying that excel found unreadable content in the file and it is needed to be repaired
```

after clicking yes and repairing the file it is showing

> Repaired Records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part (Drawing
> shape)

Comment: IMO, provided code can be reduced to only `xlsx` or `openpyxl` related, PySimpleGUI is not required in your question, then you may get the answer soon.

Comment: As it says in the openpyxl documentation, support for drawings is not complete.

Comment: i have this same issue withformulas, some of them get broken